# Animations side by side controlled by one set of buttons

Tags: animate

I am using animate package to create animations out of three sets of figures (the same number of images in each set). I would like to control all these three animations by one set of control buttons, located below them. Is there any way to do this?

Here there is the code that I am currently working on:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[controls,buttonsize=0.3cm,scale=0.3]{0.8}{"graph1_"}{1}{19}
\animategraphics[controls,buttonsize=0.3cm,scale=0.3]{0.8}{"graph2_"}{1}{19}
\animategraphics[controls,buttonsize=0.3cm,scale=0.3]{0.8}{"graph3_"}{1}{19}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would combine all three animations into one animation if possible. Less CPU usage I would assume in addition to "problem solved". Nice MWE by the way.

Answer (score 2):

The frame sets could be combined as follows, using `animateinline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \noindent%
  \begin{animateinline}[controls,width=\linewidth]{0.8}
  \multiframe{19}{i=1+1}{%
    \includegraphics{graph1_\i}%
    \includegraphics{graph2_\i}%
    \includegraphics{graph3_\i}%
  }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```